# What is a good introductory book in multivariate statistical analysis?

Tags: r, clustering, multivariate-analysis

I want to read my **first book in multivariate statistical analysis**. Are there any suggestions?

More specifically the book should contain:

- **cluster analysis**,
- **multidimensional scaling**,
- **examples from social and behavioral sciences** and
- if it possible, **examples in R**.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I read the answers for [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26372/introductory-book-for-multivariate-statistics), but:

1. the [link of the accepted answer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/richpub/listmania/fullview/R3312L94GKFZD1/) is not working,
2. the questioner doesn't specify his preferences as I want.

Comment: It's a pity that link is broken, but that's hardly sufficient reason to ask a new question. Your reason #2 is surely grounds to flag social/behavioural and R examples in your title as those are the senses in which your question is different. Covering cluster analysis and MDS in a multivariate book is not that restrictive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two standard textbooks are:

- Rencher's [Methods of Multivariate Analysis](https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/Methods+of+Multivariate+Analysis%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470178966) and
- Johnson & Wichern's [Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Johnson-Applied-Multivariate-Statistical-Analysis-Classic-Version-6th-Edition/PGM2043175.html)

Both are considered pretty classic and start from the ground-up.

I have personally used Izenman's [Modern Multivariate Statistical Techniques](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-78189-1) quite a bit but does not have a social science focus.
Through a quick Google search I came across Pituch & Steven's [Applied Multivariate Statistics for the Social Sciences](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Multivariate-Statistics-Social-Sciences/dp/0415836662/ref=pd_lpo_14_t_0/258-1101139-2783048) but I have not used it; It probably fits your requirements well though.

Comment: I like the Izenman book.

Comment: @NickCox: Agreed, I found it very matter-of-factly. (And thanks for the edit. :) )

Comment: @usεr11852 , thanks for your answer! Both books seems interesting, but Izenman seems the best. Thanks!